# Clojurescript `.-name` convention

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I've been trying to learn ClojureScript and stumbled upon some very mysterious function names.

For example:

`(.-length str)`

From the `om` docs:

```
(defn add-contact [data owner]
  (let [new-contact (-> (om/get-node owner "new-contact")
                        .-value ;;What is this?
                        parse-contact)]
    (when new-contact
      (om/transact! data :contacts #(conj % new-contact)))))
```

What is that `.-` trying to indicate?

Comment: Was `.-value` in a context where a macro would be adding parameters, ie. `(-->)` or `(->)`? It doesn't make sense on its own.

Comment: Ah -- in the `om` case, it's in `->`, so *that's* adding the argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are retrieving native JavaScript properties. Thus, `(.-length str)` would compile to the JavaScript `str.length`.

Contrast this to the ClojureScript `(.length str)`, which would compile to the method invocation `str.length()` -- a rather different thing.

---

In the `om` case given, the code is doing the following in order:

- Calling `get-node`, and taking its result
- Taking the `value` property of that result
- Calling the function `parse-contact` with that value passed.

This is because the threading macro, `->`, substitutes the results of each stage as the first argument of the next -- making that code equivalent to `(parse-contact (.-value (om/get-node owner "new-contact")))`.

Comment: Is there a place where I could read up on the relation between `(.-value)` and macros?

Comment: There's nothing special about `.-foo` in the context of macros; `->` is doing the same thing it always does.

Comment: Wow! That's awesome. So `->` is kind of a composition operator?